# Qt Assistant: programmatically clear cache?

Tags: qt

I have a Qt 4.8-based application that runs on Windows 7 and uses Qt Assistant to display documentation. I've frequently had headaches with Qt Assistant relating to the need to delete cached files whenever I update documentation (I keep reading that cache problems have been fixed in various Qt updates, but the problems I have seem to persist). This occurs when I launch Assistant from within my application or directly from the command line (with `assistant.exe -collectionFile myapp.qhc`).

This is a major problem when I'm distributing my application to users. It's not OK to expect them to delete cached files on their systems.

I couldn't find anything in the Qt documentation on how to clear the user's cached help files. Is there something I'm missing?

I have also compiled my application for Linux, and don't seem to have the same problem there. It's just Windows.

Comment: This seems to be related and not fixed as of today https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-12050